# Creating multiple icons in Windows Taskbar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have the JFrame as the parent in my GUI. In it, I present the option to launch a JDialog, which gets info from the client. The JDialog appears on a different window, and I'd like to see two different window icons appear in the Windows 7 Taskbar, one for the JFrame, and another for the JDialog. Currently, I'm only getting one icon in the taskbar, and by clicking on it, it returns the client to the main screen. (The JFrame.)

Can this behavior be overridden in Java? I'd like the behavior to be similar to that of Chrome or any other program when I have multiple windows open, i.e., to be able to hover over the window icon, and be able to choose which window to bring to the front of the display.

Comment: AFAIK, `JDialog`s are really not meant for the behaviour you looking for. `JDialog` is a sort of a disposable entity, that comes to show some information or get some from the user and then after passing the information to the program, gets disposed off. Moreover the behaviour of the Top Level Containers is mostly Operating System Driven. If you really need icons on the Taskbar, you need to use `JFrame/JWindow` , `JDialog` IMHO, is not suitable or meant for such things.

Comment: As I'm reading the JavaDocs on Dialogs and Frames, I'm beginning to come to the same conclusion. The basic Dialog class that extends Window has the characteristics you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a new JFrame, set there the icon. And then forward this newly created JFrame as the owner to the Dialog. It only depends on the owner-frame. If this is void, then the app one is taken as the default.